# Star * operator on left vs right side of an assignment statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable, iterable-unpacking

This questions stems from [`PEP 448` -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) and is present in Python 3.5 as far as I'm aware (and not back-ported to `2.x`). Specifically, in the section **Disadvantages**, the following is noted:

> Whilst `*elements, = iterable` causes `elements` to be a `list`, 
>   `elements = *iterable`, causes `elements` to be a `tuple`. The reason for this may confuse people unfamiliar with the construct.

Which does indeed hold, for `iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, the first case yields a `list`:

```
>>> *elements, = iterable
>>> elements
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

While for the second case a `tuple` is created:

```
>>> elements = *iterable,
>>> elements
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Being unfamiliar with the concept, I am confused. Can anyone explain this behavior? Does the starred expression act differently depending on the side it is on?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The difference between these two cases are explained when also taking into consideration the initial PEP for extended unpacking: [`PEP 3132 -- Extended iterable unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

In the Abstract for that PEP we can see that:

> This PEP proposes a change to iterable unpacking syntax, allowing to specify a "catch-all" name which ***will be assigned a list*** of all items not assigned to a "regular" name.

<sup>*(emphasis mine)*</sup>

**So in the first case**, after executing:

```
*elements, = iterable
```

`elements` is always going to be a `list` containing all the items in the `iterable`.

Even though it seems similar in both cases, the `*` in this case (left-side) means: catch everything that isn't assigned to a name and assign it to the starred expression. It works in a similar fashion as `*args` and `**kwargs` do in **function definitions**.

```
def spam(*args, **kwargs): 
    """ args and kwargs group positional and keywords respectively """
```

**The second case (right-side) is somewhat different**. Here we don't have the `*` working in a "catch everything" way as much as we have it working as it usually does in **function calls**. It expands the contents of the iterable it is attached to. So, the statement:

```
elements = *iterable,
```

can be viewed as:

```
elements = 1, 2, 3, 4,
```

which is another way for a `tuple` to be initialized.

Do note, a `list` can be created by simple using `elements = [*iterable]` which will unpack the contents of `iterable` in `[]` and result in an assignments of the form `elements = [1, 2, 3, 4]`.