# Extracting individual numbers from string (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a long code e.g `545362783` and would like to add the consists numbers together and multiply them, like `(1*5)+(2*4)+(3*5)+(4*3)+(5*6)` etc.

Is there a simple solution to get them as a integer so I could use these in math. 
Many thanks!

Comment: There is a simple solution but its not robust. To make it robust you will probably need a parser. You can use Python's `ast` module but it will parse more than just math: `>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('(1 + 2) + (3 + 4)'))` will give you a parsed expression:
`'Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=BinOp(left=Num(n=1), op=Add(), right=Num(n=2)), op=Add(), right=BinOp(left=Num(n=3), op=Add(), right=Num(n=4))))])'`

Comment: Hi and welcome onboard of StackOverflow. As your question is generally clear, a more structured question, especially with an example that can easily be copied would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
s = '545362783'

a = sum(x * int(c) for x, c in zip(range(1, len(s) + 1), s))
print(a)
# 222
```

What is happening is the following:

- `s` is just a string so looping through it will give each char
- `range(1, len(s) + 1)` will give integers from `1` until the length of `s`
- `zip()` is grouping its arguments so that `1` and `'5'` (etc.) are yielded at the same time by the `for` loop
- then, `c` which contains the characters, is converted to `int`
- finally all is multiplied together and summed up with `sum()`

---

The same could be done a little more efficiently `enumerate()` (making good use of the `start` parameter, [similarly to what is done in @shahaf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58284298/5218354)):

```
a = sum(x * int(c) for x, c in enumerate(s, 1))
```

This is essentially the same as above but a bit more elegant (and probably also faster). The behavior of `enumerate()` is just to yield an index accompanying the object being looped through.

Comment: That is the solution I'd prefer, I didn't know I did not need a list comprehension inside the sum, though.

Comment: `sum()` is fine with a generator and this avoids creating the intermediate unnecessary `list`.

Comment: Hey. Works like a charm. Would it still be possible to loop through each number but the last one. Let's say I have 10 charecters, but i'd like to only multiply with 9 of them. Thanks for the help!

Comment: just slice the list: sum(a * int(b) for a, b in enumerate(s[:-1], 1)) should work.

Answer (score 1):

try unpacking

```
s = '545362783'
# --> to map each character of the string to a list:
print([*s])
['5', '4', '5', '3', '6', '2', '7', '8', '3']

# --> to map each character of the string directly to a list of integers:
# (thanks Mykola Zotko for the comment!)
print(list(map(int, s)))
[5, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 8, 3]
```

more on the unpacking operator * see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950690/python-unpacking-operator).

Comment: @MeMyself: it's more of a general solution to get individual elements from an iterable like a string in this case. For the specific calculation you mentioned in your question, I think [norok2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58284389/10197418) is pretty nice.

Comment: Try `list(map(int, s))`

Comment: @MykolaZotko: thanks for the comment, made an edit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can write a fairly simple method to do it, smth like so

```
num_str = "545362783"
total = 0;
for idx, num in enumerate(num_str, 1):
  total += idx * int(num)
```

Comment: Nice use of the `start` parameter in `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Solution. I hope it may help u:

```
a = list(str(545362783))
count = 1
c = []
for i in a:
    b = count * int(i)
    c.append(b)
    count = count + 1

sum_of_a = sum(c)
print(sum_of_a)
```

Output:

```
222
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_substring(string):
    string = '545362783'
    multi = []
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
       multiplied = int(i+1) * int(string[i])
       multi.append(multiplied) 

print (multi)
print (sum(multi))
```

You may try this.

Output:

[5, 8, 15, 12, 30, 12, 49, 64, 27]

222