# call a function with one argument and a list as inputs

Tags: python, function

I have a function run_model which takes in 5 arguments

```
run_model(lr_model,X_train_full,y_train_full,X_test_full,y_test_full)
```

can I call the function with one defined argument and a list

```
run_model(lr_model,[full_data])

full_data = (X_train_full,y_train_full,X_test_full,y_test_full)
```

Comment: `run_model(lr_model, *full_data)`

Comment: WOW! Amazing. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the unpacking `*` feature of python. This operator unpacks the values of a list into separate values, so you can pass this into a function.

```
full_data = (X_train_full,y_train_full,X_test_full,y_test_full)
run_model(lr_model, *full_data)
```

This is equivalent to passing every value separately.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options when declaring a function to accept many arguments

- accept a wildcard list of `*args`
- pass in the argument as a list `foo(arg1, [arg2])`

If you mean passing in all the args to a function set up to accept 5 (or any number), as **@Paul M** notes, you can [unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950690/python-unpacking-operator) the arguments to a function with `*`

This also works for named arguments, but you might use `**kwargs` to accept and `**` to unpack from a dictionary

```py
>>> "{a} {c} {a}".format(**{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3})
'1 3 1'
```

NOTE the names `args` and `kwargs` are by-convention, but choosing something else may cause confusion