# Python Dictionaries: Different way to iterate through a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am searching for a different way to access every key in a dictionary within a for loop. Underneath, there is an example code, where I iterate through a dictionary and access every key with the help of a counter and a if statement. Is there another way to access the keys, without a counter or an if statement?

```
def string_to_dict(csv):
    dict = []
    tmp = csv.splitlines()
    
    for i in tmp:
        tmp_dict = {"vorname" : "none", "nachname" : "none", "email" : "none"};
        tmp_i= i.split(",")
        counter = 0;

        for si in tmp_i:
            if counter ==0:
                tmp_dict["vorname"] = si
                counter =counter + 1
            elif counter == 1:
                tmp_dict["nachname"] = si
                counter = counter + 1
            else:
                tmp_dict["email"] = si
        dict.append(tmp_dict)
```

```
csv = """Donald,Duck,d.duck@entenhausen.com
    Wiley,Coyote,whiley@canyon.org
    Road,Runner,roadrunner@canyon.org"""
```

Comment: Maybe [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) could be useful for you

Comment: also, using `dict` as variable name is not good because it overrides the built-in `dict`

Comment: As already suggested, if you're manipulating a CSV file, use the standard library's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module. It's easier than trying to do all the parsing yourself, and takes care properly of all possible problems of quoting and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the loop if you already expect name, surname and email.

```
def string_to_dict(csv):
    dict = []
    tmp = csv.splitlines()
    
    for i in tmp:
        tmp_dict = {"vorname" : "none", "nachname" : "none", "email" : "none"};
        tmp_i= i.split(",")

        tmp_dict["vorname"] = tmp_i[0]
        tmp_dict["nachname"] = tmp_i[1]
        tmp_dict["email"] = tmp_i[2]

        dict.append(tmp_dict)
```

We can keep iterating to improve the solution:

```
def string_to_dict(csv):
    dict = []
    tmp = csv.splitlines()
    
    for i in tmp:
        tmp_dict = {"vorname" : None, "nachname" : None, "email" : None};
        tmp_i= i.split(",")

        tmp_dict["vorname"] = tmp_i[0]
        tmp_dict["nachname"] = tmp_i[1]
        tmp_dict["email"] = tmp_i[2]

        dict.append(tmp_dict)
```

And even more (if you want to use a protected keyword like dict, naming convention is to use an underscore after it):

```
def string_to_dict(csv):
    dict_ = []
    for line in csv.splitlines():
        vor_name, nach_name, email = line.split(",")
        dict_.append({"vorname" : vor_name, "nachname" : nach_name, "email" : email})
    return dict_
```

And with list comprehensions:

```
def string_to_dict(csv):
    def _parse_item(vor_name, nach_name, email):
        return {"vorname" : vor_name, "nachname" : nach_name, "email" : email}
    return [_parse_item(*line.split(",")) for line in csv.splitlines()]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I was trying to get it also done with a comprehension, but I do not know how to express it in one line. What I am working on right now is the following, but its not working. Can you help me out?

```split_dict = [x.split(",") for x in tmp]
    append_dict = {tmp[x.index] = ("vorname": x[0]) for x, y in split_dict}```

Comment: it can be done using an auxiliar function! see the updated answer

Comment: wow thats cool. I havent gotten it to work yet, but I understood what you have written down

Comment: To make the comprehension work, I passed all the indexes into the function: `return([_parse_item(line.split(",")[0],line.split(",")[1], line.split(",")[2]) for line in csv.splitlines()])`

Comment: That's not a good idea, since you compute the split 3 times. I've updated my typo!

Comment: What does * stand for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950690/python-unpacking-operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230455/discussion-between-luis-michael-luethi-and-miquelvir).

Answer (score 1):

If you want minimal changes to what you have done so far, you can just get `list of keys` and use the `index` value (counter variable in your case), something like this:

```
for i in tmp:
    tmp_dict = {"vorname" : "none", "nachname" : "none", "email" : "none"};
    tmp_i= i.split(",")
    counter = 0;
    keys = [*temp_dict.keys()]    # List of Keys
    for si in tmp_i:
        tmp_dict[keys[counter]] = si  # Key at index counter
        counter += 1
    dict.append(tmp_dict)
```

**Sample Run:**

```
>>string_to_dict(csv)
[{'vorname': '    Road', 'nachname': 'Runner', 'email': 'roadrunner@canyon.org'}, {'vorname': '    Road', 'nachname': 'Runner', 'email': 'roadrunner@canyon.org'}, {'vorname': '    Road', 'nachname': 'Runner', 'email': 'roadrunner@canyon.org'}]
```

**Another Note:** You're naming the variable as `dict` You should avoid that since it's a keyword in Python

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the fact that you are not trying to iterate over a dictionary but to create a list containing dictionary entries from a CSV format string.
secondly there are a lot of python syntactic mistakes and errors in your code.
Refrain from using reserved word such as "dict" as parameter names.

You can use this code snippet as a start if it helps you but I recommend brushing up on python syntax and best practices.

```
result = []
for line in csv.splitlines():
    vorname, nachname, email = line.split(",")
    result.append(
        {"vorname": vorname.strip(), "nachname": nachname.strip(), "email": email.strip()})
```

This can be done also using list comprehension, but is much less readable