# re-order some of the sheets in a workbook python

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, export, columnsorting

I have a data frame named "master", with columns names like this:

```
Code, 7/1/2021 , 6/29/2021, 5/22/2021, 6/1/2021
```

In order to re-arrange them by date, I created a list:

```
dates = list(master.columns.values)
```

since I just want to sort everything by "Code", I removed it from the list and sort them:

```
dates.remove('Code')
dates.sort()
```

in the last part to re-arrange them I'm using this:

```
master = master[['SOURCE', dates]]
```

but it's not working, it's giving me this error:

```
> KeyError: '["\'5/22/2021\',\'6/1/2021\',\'6/29/2021\',\'7/1/2021\'"]
> not in index'
```

Comment: Try `master = master[['SOURCE', *dates]]` Note the `*`

Comment: Hey I’m sorry but how could I find more information about this? How do you call this trick?

Comment: `*` can be used as *"unpacking"* operator... more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950690/python-unpacking-operator