# How can I make a recursive function that returns a list of sum of the same index given two lists.?

Tags: python, recursion

How can I make a recursive function that returns a list of sum of the same index given two lists.?

I want to make it a recursive function only.

for example:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [2,4,6]
```

a recursive function will return a new list [3,6,9]

The language should also be python.

Thank you. I just having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: It has to be recursive? It would be easier to write it non-recursively.

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: I cannot make an attempt because I do not know what to write.

Comment: I have to use recursive because it was the instruction. I understand that there is something that is more efficient but this was just for the sake of showcasing how recursive function works.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
def recursive_sum(a, b):
    
    # if one of the list is empty return the empty list
    if not a or not b:
        return []
    # find the sum of each of the first elements
    val = a[0] + b[0]
    
    # return the concatenation of the first sum with the recursive sum for the rest of the lists 
    return [val, *recursive_sum(a[1:], b[1:])]
```

**Output**

```
[3, 6, 9]
```

As an alternative suggested by @Stef use:

```
def recursive_sum(a, b):
    if not a or not b:
        return []
    return [a[0] + b[0]] + recursive_sum(a[1:], b[1:])
```

The expression:

```
*recursive_sum(a[1:], b[1:])
```

is known as unpacking, basically one could said that
`[1, 2, 3]` is equivalent to `[1, *[2, 3]]`, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950690/python-unpacking-operator) for more information.

Comment: May I ask you a favor? Could you briefly explain what is happening in this line 


return [a[0] + b[0], *recursive_sum(a[1:], b[1:])]

Comment: especially the multiply sign

Comment: @Jakeyyyy The asterisk in this context means unpacking, not multiplication. `x = [b, c, d]; y = [a, *x]` is basically the same as `x = [b, c, d]; y = [a, b, c, d]` or `x = [b, c, d]; y = [a] + x`. So `return [a[0] + b[0], *recursive_sum(a[1:], b[1:])]` is the same as `return [a[0] + b[0]] + recursive_sum(a[1:], b[1:])`

Comment: @Stef for the last part, are you using that the asterisk is equal to the plus sign? since that is the only you changed in the original example. I tried the one that has plus sign but I got an error.

Comment: No, the asterisk is not a plus sign. Note how I changed the brackets, too. The asterisk means unpacking. `[a, *[b, c, d]]` is the same as `[a, b, c, d]`. The result is the same as `[a] + [b, c, d]`. But the asterisk is certainly not a plus sign.

Comment: @Jakeyyyy Added a few explanations to the answer