# How to declare variables from an input() with different class ( int and str)

Tags: python, string, integer

```
iLig1, iCol1 , iLig2 , iCol2 , carac = map(int, input ().split ())
```

hello I try to get this ligne of input in my code right, I get 5 variables from an input that look like this:

```
1 12 7 14 u
```

how can I declare the last one as a str properly,
I tried to consider them all as str and convert the 4 first as int but I cannot interpret str as int (you know..)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You don't seem to be *declaring* anything.  Process the first 4 items with one line of code, and the last with a different line of code.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that `"convert the 4 first as int"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Iterable Unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/) : `(*)`.

```
# we suppose input is -> 1 2 3 4 u
>>> *i, j = input().split()

>>> print(i)
['1', '2', '3', '4']

>>> print(j)
u

>>> list(map(int, i))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: May as well unpack on the same line as the `split`; no real benefit to not doing so, and it demonstrates a benefit of unpacking that simple slicing and indexing can't match cleanly.

Comment: Thank you for the unpacking operator (*) tips, I learned something new and this is basically exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @ClémentMaujean, You're welcome, reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950690/python-unpacking-operator) is good. Maybe for more detail and use unpacking in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
iLig1, iCol1 , iLig2 , iCol2 , carac = [int(x) if i<4 else x for i,x in enumerate(input ().split ())]
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner that converts the first 4 to int and the last to str

```py
iLig1, iCol1 , iLig2 , iCol2 , carac = map(lambda f: f[1](f[0]), zip(input().split(), [int, int, int, int, str]))
```