# If we could use def func(*args), why is *args = (1,2) wrong?

Tags: python

When I was learning the details of unpacking operation in python, I did some programming to practice. When I wrote: `a, *b = (1,2,3)`, I got `b = [2,3]`.

After doing this, I suddenly noticed the `*` operation also exists in python elsewhere, such as arbitrary argument in python functions. And I write:

```py
def func(a, *args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
func(1,2,3)
```

Output for this code was:

```
2
3
```

So I tried to figure out how this worked. This is how I think: when I called `func(1,2,3)`, python interpreter would do the assignment: `a, *args = 1, 2, 3`, so `a=1, args=[2,3]`. But when I added `print(type(args))` in `func`, the output was `tuple`. After doing this, I tested `def func(*args)` which worked as well. Even the type was not the expected one, but the elements in the args were.

Then, I did another test: `*args=[1,2]`, but I got an Error, which is `SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple`.

Now, I was confused about the `*` in the unpacking operation and the arbitrary argument. The question is what role does `*` play in these 2 situations?

I found that others also had doubts about expression like `*args=[1,2,3]`, but they didn't mention the relation with arbitrary argument.

Comment: I guess because unpacking must be performed in a container. When you run `a, *args = 1, 2, 3`, the left-hand side of the `=` is a tuple. Not with `*args = 1, 2, 3`. Also, what would you expect `*args = 1, 2, 3` to do compared to `args = 1, 2, 3`?

Comment: When I ran a, *b = (1,2,3), I got b = [1,2], I got b=[2,3] as one would expect. Typo?

Comment: It sounds like the rules are a little arbitrary, but there is never a need to write `*args=[1,2]`, when `args=[1,2]` does the same thing.

Comment: in this context, `*` is an unpacking operator and when used in the context of an assignment, must be an unambiguous  member of an unpacking tuple or list. Specifically, the left hand side of the assignment must be a list or tuple to unpack into and there can be no ambiguity about how the unpacking operator works to collect "the rest"

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950690/python-unpacking-operator

Comment: I see at least two actual questions in this question.  First, why do you get a tuple when using `*` in a function argument and a list when using it in a regular assignment?  And second, why must the `*` element be part of a tuple for a regular assignment?  I must admit I don't have the answer to either.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, @wander95 is right, I got b=[2,3] instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```py
*a, = (1,2,3)
```

or this

```py
[*a] = (1,2,3)
```

essentially when you do

```py
a, b = [1,2]
```

it is the same as

```
(a, b) = [1,2]
```

It is getting parsed as a tuple unpacking. When creating a tuple with a single element you need to add a comma at the end to prevent it from being parsed as a parenthetical: e.g. `(a,)` The same thing applied here. You need to add a comma when destructuring a single item to signify that you want tuple destructuring.

Comment: I don't think this does an adequate job of explaining why the left side of the assignment needs to be a tuple.

Comment: @MarkRansom Make another answer?

Comment: I don't have a better answer myself.  It's a mystery to me why that is a requirement.

Comment: it's just that the only reason that `*` works in assignments is because it is a tuple unpacking. So if you use `*` and it isn't in a tuple unpacking then it is invalid syntax

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand, but it still seems extremely convoluted.

Comment: Indeed the [grammar specification for an assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html#:~:text=assignment%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20NAME%20%27%3A%27%20expression,~%20(yield_expr%20%7C%20star_expressions)) is quite drawn out