# Why does splatting create a tuple on the rhs but a list on the lhs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, splat

Consider, for example,

```
squares = *map((2).__rpow__, range(5)),
squares
# (0, 1, 4, 9, 16)

*squares, = map((2).__rpow__, range(5))
squares
# [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

So, all else being equal we get a list when splatting on the lhs and a tuple when splatting on the rhs.

Why?

Is this by design, and if yes, what's the rationale? Or, if not, are there any technical reasons? Or is this just how it is, no particular reason?

Comment: Also, relevant, though not a dupe. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636785/star-operator-on-left-vs-right-side-of-an-assignment-statement)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The fact that you get a tuple on the RHS has nothing to do with the splat. The splat just unpacks your `map` iterator. What you unpack it *into* is decided by the fact that you've used tuple syntax:

```
*whatever,
```

instead of list syntax:

```
[*whatever]
```

or set syntax:

```
{*whatever}
```

You could have gotten a list or a set. You just told Python to make a tuple.

---

On the LHS, a splatted assignment target always produces a list. It doesn't matter whether you use "tuple-style"

```
*target, = whatever
```

or "list-style"

```
[*target] = whatever
```

syntax for the target list. The syntax looks a lot like the syntax for creating a list or tuple, but target list syntax is an entirely different thing.

The syntax you're using on the left was introduced in [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), to support use cases like

```
first, *rest = iterable
```

In an unpacking assignment, elements of an iterable are assigned to unstarred targets by position, and if there's a starred target, any extras are stuffed into a list and assigned to that target. [A list was chosen instead of a tuple to make further processing easier](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#acceptance). Since you have *only* a starred target in your example, all items go in the "extras" list assigned to that target.

Answer (score 31):

This is specified in [PEP-0448 disadvantages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#disadvantages)

> Whilst `*elements, = iterable` causes elements to be a list, `elements = *iterable,` causes elements to be a tuple. The reason for this may confuse people unfamiliar with the construct.

Also as per: [PEP-3132 specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#specification)

> This PEP proposes a change to iterable unpacking syntax, allowing to specify a "catch-all" name which will be assigned a list of all items not assigned to a "regular" name.

Also mentioned here: [Python-3 exprlists](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#exprlists)

> Except when part of a list or set display, an expression list containing at least one comma yields a tuple.
>   The trailing comma is required only to create a single tuple (a.k.a. a singleton); it is optional in all other cases. A single expression without a trailing comma doesn’t create a tuple, but rather yields the value of that expression. (To create an empty tuple, use an empty pair of parentheses: ().)

This might also be seen in a simpler example here, where elements in a list

```
In [27]: *elements, = range(6)                                                                                                                                                      

In [28]: elements                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[28]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and here, where elements is a tuple

```
In [13]: elements = *range(6),                                                                                                                                                      

In [14]: elements                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[14]: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

From what I could understand from the comments and the other answers:

- The first behaviour is to keep in-line with the existing [arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) used in functions ie.`*args`
- The second behaviour is to be able to use the variables on LHS further down in the evaluation, so making it a list, a mutable value rather than a tuple makes more sense

Comment: While the PEP does refer to a reason, it doesn't appear to actually give one.

Comment: Yes it doesn't, I am trying to find a reason myself @PaulPanzer :)

Comment: [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#specification) says that `*elements, = range(6)` will create a list on the left-hand side. PEP 448 says that `elements = *range(6),` has generalized unpacking in a _tuple display_, `(*range(6),)` with implicit parentheses, creating a tuple on the right-hand side. (cc @PaulPanzer)

Answer (score 19):

There is an indication of the reason why at the end of [PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#id11):

> Acceptance
>
> After a short discussion on the python-3000 list [1], the
> PEP was accepted by Guido in its current form. Possible changes
> discussed were:
>
> [...]
>
> Make the starred target a tuple instead of a list. This would be
> consistent with a function's *args, but make further processing of the
> result harder.

[1] https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007198.html

So, the advantage of having a mutable list instead of an immutable tuple seems to be the reason.

Answer (score 13):

not a complete answer, but disassembling gives some clues:

```
from dis import dis

def a():
    squares = (*map((2).__rpow__, range(5)),)
    # print(squares)

print(dis(a))
```

disassembles as

```
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (map)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__rpow__)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             14 BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK       1
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (squares)
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

while

```
def b():
    *squares, = map((2).__rpow__, range(5))
print(dis(b))
```

results in

```
 11           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (map)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__rpow__)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             14 UNPACK_EX                0
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (squares)
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

the [doc on `UNPACK_EX`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-UNPACK_EX) states:

> UNPACK_EX(counts)
>
> Implements assignment with a starred target: Unpacks an iterable in TOS into individual values, where the total number of values can be
>   smaller than the number of items in the iterable: one of the new
>   values will be a **list** of all leftover items.
>
> The low byte of counts is the number of values before the list value, the high byte of counts the number of values after it. The
>   resulting values are put onto the stack right-to-left.

(emphasis mine). while [`BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK) returns a `tuple`:

> BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK(count)
>
> Pops count iterables from the stack, joins them in a single **tuple**, and pushes the result. Implements iterable unpacking in tuple displays
>   (*x, *y, *z).

Comment: So would that be a technical reason or no reason?

Comment: no, i do not see an argument for a reason here... it might be beneficial to have something mutable in the second case...  but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 10):

For the RHS, there is not much of an issue. the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636785/star-operator-on-left-vs-right-side-of-an-assignment-statement) states it well:

> We have it working as it usually does in function calls. It expands
>   the contents of the iterable it is attached to. So, the statement:
>
> ```
> elements = *iterable
> ```
>
> can be viewed as:
>
> ```
> elements = 1, 2, 3, 4,
> ```
>
> which is another way for a tuple to be initialized.

Now, for the LHS,
Yes, there are technical reasons for the LHS using a list, as indicated in the discussion around [the initial PEP 3132 for extending unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

The reasons can be gleaned from the conversation on the PEP(added at the end).

Essentially it boils down to a couple key factors:

- The LHS needed to support a "starred expression" that was not necessarily restricted to the end only.
- The RHS needed to allow various sequence types to be accepted, including iterators.
- The combination of the two points above required manipulation/mutation of the contents after accepting them into the starred expression.
- An alternative approach to handling, one to mimic the iterator fed on the RHS, even leaving implementation difficulties aside, was shot down by Guido for its inconsistent behaviour.
- Given all the factors above, a tuple on LHS would have to be a list first, and then converted. This approach would then just add overhead, and did not invite any further discussion.

**Summary**: A combination of various factors led to the decision to allow a list on the LHS, and the reasons fed off of each other.

---

Relevant extract for disallowing inconsistent types:

> The important use case in Python for the proposed semantics is when
>   you have a variable-length record, the first few items of which are
>   interesting, and the rest of which is less so, but not unimportant.
>   (If you wanted to throw the rest away, you'd just write a, b, c =
>   x[:3] instead of a, b, c, *d = x.) It is much more convenient for this
>   use case if the type of d is fixed by the operation, so you can count
>   on its behavior.
>
> There's a bug in the design of filter() in Python 2 (which will be
>   fixed in 3.0 by turning it into an iterator BTW): if the input is a
>   tuple, the output is a tuple too, but if the input is a list *or
>   anything else*, the output is a list.  That's a totally insane
>   signature, since it means that you can't count on the result being a
>   list, *nor* on it being a tuple -- **if you need it to be one or the
>   other, you have to convert it to one, which is a waste of time and
>   space. Please let's not repeat this design bug.**
>   -Guido
>
> ---

I have also tried to recreate a partially quoted conversation that pertains to the summary above.[Source](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007198.html)
*Emphasis mine.*

1.

> In argument lists, *args exhausts iterators, converting them to
>   tuples. I think it would be confusing if *args in tuple unpacking
>   didn't do the same thing.
>
> **This brings up the question of why the patch produces lists, not
>   tuples.** What's the reasoning behind that?
>
> STeVe

2.

> IMO, it's likely that **you would like to further process the resulting
>   sequence, including modifying it.**
>
> Georg

3.

> Well if that's what you're aiming at, then I'd expect it to be more
>   useful to have the unpacking generate **not lists, but the same type you
>   started with,** e.g. if I started with a string, I probably want to
>   continue using strings:: 
>   --*additional text snipped off*

4.

> When **dealing with an iterator, you don't know the length in advance,**
>   so the only way to get a tuple would be to **produce a list first and
>   then create a tuple from it.**
>   Greg

5.

> Yep.  That was one of the reasons it was **suggested that the *args**
>   should only **appear at the end** of the tuple unpacking.
>
> STeVe

*couple convos skipped*

6.

> I don't think that returning the type given is a goal that should be
>   attempted, because **it can only ever work for a fixed set of known
>   types.** Given an arbitrary sequence type, there is no way of knowing
>   how to create a new instance of it with specified contents.
>
> -- Greg

*skipped convos*

7.

> > I'm suggesting, that:
> >
> > - lists return lists
> > - tuples return tuples
> > - XYZ containers return XYZ containers
> > - non-container iterables return iterators.
>
> How do you propose to distinguish between the last two cases?
>   **Attempting to slice it and catching an exception is not acceptable**,
>   IMO, as it can too easily mask bugs.
>
> -- Greg

8.

> But I expect less useful. **It won't support "a, *b, c = "
>   either.** From an **implementation POV**, if you have an **unknown object on
>   the RHS, you have to try slicing it before you try iterating over it;
>   this may cause problems** e.g. if the object happens to be a defaultdict
>   -- since x[3:] is implemented as x[slice(None, 3, None)], the defaultdict will give you its default value. I'd much rather define
>   this in terms of iterating over the object until it is exhausted,
>   which can be optimized for certain known types like lists and tuples.
>
> -- 
>   --Guido van Rossum

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: You get a `tuple` on the RHS because you asked for one. You get a `list` on the LHS because it is easier.

---

It is important to keep in mind that the RHS is evaluated before the LHS - this is why `a, b = b, a` works. The difference then becomes apparent when splitting the assignment and using additional capabilities for the LHS and RHS:

```
# RHS: Expression List
a = head, *tail
# LHS: Target List
*leading, last = a
```

In short, while the two look similar, they are entirely different things. The RHS is an expression to create *one* `tuple` from *all* names - the LHS is a binding to *multiple* names from *one* `tuple`. Even if you see the LHS as a tuple of names, that does not restrict the type of each name.

---

The RHS is an [expression list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) - a `tuple` literal without the optional `()` parentheses. This is the same as how `1, 2` creates a tuple even without parentheses, and how enclosing `[]` or `{}` create a `list` or `set`. The `*tail` just means unpacking *into* this `tuple`.

> *New in version 3.5:* Iterable unpacking in expression lists, originally proposed by [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

The LHS does not create one value, it binds values to multiple names. With a catch-all name such as `*leading`, the binding is not known up-front in all cases. Instead, the catch-all contains whatever remains.

Using a `list` to store values makes this simples - the values for trailing names can be efficiently removed from the end. The remaining `list` then contains the exactly the values for the catch-all name. In fact, this is exactly what [CPython does](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#changes-to-the-bytecode-interpreter):

> - collect all items for mandatory targets before the starred one
> - collect all remaining items from the iterable in a list
> - **pop items** for mandatory targets after the starred one from the list
> - push the single items and the resized list on the stack

Even when the LHS has a catch-all name without trailing names, it is a `list` for consistency.

Comment: "For consistency, RHS and LHS are always of the same type, i.e. tuple and list." - what? What are you talking about?

Comment: Also, you might think the way the RHS works makes it easy to build a tuple, but in fact, Python [actually builds a list first and then builds a tuple from the list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Python/ceval.c#L2283). Trying to build a tuple directly would cause complications when the size of the result can't be determined up front.

Comment: @user2357112 I have made some extensive changes to remove some red herrings that unintentionally implied overlapping motivation for both the RHS and LHS. The point is that it is simpler for the LHS to use a ``list``. The RHS *has* to be a ``tuple``, the same way ``{1, 2}`` has to be a ``set``. Whether there is some ``list``->``tuple`` conversion underneath does not change that.

Answer (score 4):

## Using `a = *b,`:

If you do:

```
a = *[1, 2, 3],
```

It would give:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

**Because:**

1. Unpacking and some other stuff give tuples in default, but if you say i.e

`[*[1, 2, 3]]`

Output:

`[1, 2, 3]` as a `list` since I do a `list`, so `{*[1, 2, 3]}` will give a `set`.

2. Unpacking gives three elements, and for `[1, 2, 3]` it really just does

`1, 2, 3`

Which outputs:

`(1, 2, 3)`

That's what unpacking does.

**The main part:**

Unpacking simply executes:

```
1, 2, 3
```

For:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Which is a tuple:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

Actually this creates a list, and changes it into a tuple.

## Using `*a, = b`:

Well, this is really gonna be:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Since it isn't:

```
*a, b = [1, 2, 3]
```

Or something similar, there is not much about this.

1. <del>It is equivalent without `*` and `,`</del>, not fully, it just always gives a list.
2. This is really almost only used for multiple variables i.e:

`*a, b = [1, 2, 3]`

One thing is that no matter what it stores a list type:

```
>>> *a, = {1,2,3}
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> *a, = (1,2,3)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Also it would be a strange to have:

```
a, *b = 'hello'
```

And:

```
print(b)
```

To be:

```
'ello'
```

Then it doesn't seem like splatting.

Also `list` have more functions than others, easier to handle.

There is probably no reason for this to happen, it really a decision in Python.

The `a = *b,` section there is a reason, in "The main part:" section.

## Summary:

Also as @Devesh mentioned here in [PEP 0448 disadvantages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#disadvantages):

> Whilst *elements, = iterable **causes elements to be a list**, elements = *iterable, **causes elements to be a tuple**. The reason for this may confuse people unfamiliar with the construct.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Why bother, this doesn't really matter for us, why not just use the below if you want a list:

```
print([*a])
```

Or a tuple:

```
print((*a))
```

And a set:

```
print({*a})
```

And so on...