# Why does unpacking of `*a, b = something` makes `a` always `list` type?

Tags: python, list, types, unpack, iterable-unpacking

I was just testing around with unpacking,

And I realized:

```
*a, b = {1, 2, 3}
```

Makes `a` a `list`, not a `set`.

With it as:

```
[1, 2]
```

And I tried:

```
*a, = {1, 2, 3}
```

Expecting a `set`, but it still becomes a `list` as:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

And even with tuples:

```
*a, = (1, 2, 3)
```

It does the same `list` thing as `set` does.

This doesn't seem right to me for some reason, I think this is on purpose.

Comment: How could it possibly preserve the type of an arbitrary RHS iterable? What if the RHS was a `map` object, or a file?

Comment: See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/. "This PEP proposes a change to iterable unpacking syntax, allowing to specify a "catch-all" name which will be assigned a *list* of all items... "

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237733/why-does-splatting-create-a-tuple-on-the-rhs-but-a-list-on-the-lhs covers a lot about this from different viewpoints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Possible changes discussed were:

[...]

> Try to give the starred target the same type as the source iterable,
>   for example, `b` in `a, *b = 'hello'` would be assigned the string `'ello'`.
>   This may seem nice, but is impossible to get right consistently with
>   all iterables.

Source: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/